# How do display activity owner name in Angular?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, public-activity

I'm trying to build a activity stream in my rails/angular application using the [Public Activity](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity) gem and the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity?autoplay=true). It's a pretty easy set up on the rails side, but I'm having some trouble with the angular side of things.

I've tracked my movie model. So when a movie is added it's recorded as a new activity. I've created a template, service and controller (on the angular side) to display the activity.

The template,

```
%ul{"ng-repeat" => "activitie in activities"}
  %li {{ activitie }}
```

When I view the template in my app it displays like this (which is expected).

```
{"id":2,"trackable_id":5,"trackable_type":"Movie","owner_id":1,"owner_type":"User","key":"movie.create","parameters":{},"recipient_id":null,"recipient_type":null,"created_at":"2015-12-30T11:55:06.766Z","updated_at":"2015-12-30T11:55:06.766Z"}
```

Ofcourse this is not how I want to display the data, but here it gets tricky. In the railscast Ryan adds this code to his template,

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <div class="activity">
    <%= link_to activity.owner.name, activity.owner if activity.owner %>
    <%= render_activity activity %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So he uses `activity.owner.name` to present the name. But I have no idea how to get this result in Angular. The `owner_id` is the id of the user that added the movie, but I don't know how to display it through Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join with the users table to incorporate the users name.

```
PublicActivity::Activity.
  joins("INNER JOIN users ON users.id = activities.owner_id").
  select("activities.*, users.name")
```

Now you should be able to call `activity.name`.